# Drawing a polygon from the midpoints of another polygon

Tags: c#

I am trying to draw the shape attached in a link to this question, where each consecutive triangle would rely on the midpoint of the sides from the former triangle to be drawn. I have been able to input the code to draw the largest triangle but I can't figure out how to draw the other two triangles inside the larger triangle, I know this might be a trivial question but I can't seem to figure it out, I have done research on how to do it and tried watching youtube videos to help but still stuck. Quite new to coding and my knowledge of c# is limited, any help or guidance on where to check/read to prefer a solution would really be appreciated

Shape:

[image: Three Triangles]

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
    PointF v1 = new PointF(100.0F, 100.0F);
    PointF v2 = new PointF(500.0F, 100.0F);
    PointF v3 = new PointF(300.0F, 446.0F);
    PointF[] curvePoints = { v1, v2, v3 };
    e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(blackPen, curvePoints);
}
```

Comment: Please don't abuse tags.

Comment: noticed that the link I posted was not working, please use this link to have an idea of what I am trying to achieve, it's amongst one of the shapes. Thank you http://www.rahul.net/raithel/otfw/newsign.html

Comment: What you're trying to draw is similar to [Sierpiński Triangle](https://nrich.maths.org/4757), perhaps you can get some inspiration from that?

Comment: Thank you, this helps. But I am implementing it with object-oriented programming, I have an idea of the formula I should use now though. It's the implementation that's a bit tricky

Comment: @JohnOviasogie this is a programming site not a math site. So if you already know the formula you want to implement perhaps you can include it in the post and preferably show what you have already tried to code it.

Comment: @CompuChip that's true, should have tried coding out the formula and posting if I don't quite get it, it shows effort. Would be sure to do this when next I have a question. Thank you

Comment: ```PointF w1 = PointF.Subtract(v2,v1)/2 +v1;``` Did research and found this formula, but then it comes up with an error "cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.PointF' to 'System.Drawing.size'. And neither v1 or v2 are "size" objects. So I don't know why I get the error. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

The halfway point between `v1` and `v2` is:
`w1 = v1 + (v2 - v1)/2`
You can get w2 and w3 the same way to form the inner triangle. Then just repeat the calculation with w1,w2,w3 as input.

The above is just pseudocode. The addition and subtraction operators for PointF take a SizeF as input, so your code would be:

```
//example input
PointF v1 = new PointF(10, 10);
PointF v2 = new PointF(50, 50);

//calculation
PointF v2minv1 = v2 - new SizeF(v1.X, v1.Y); // (v2 - v1)
SizeF v2midv1 = new SizeF(v2minv1.X / 2f, v2minv1.Y / 2f); // (v2 - v1) /2
PointF w1 = v1 + v2midv1; // v1 + (v2- v1)/2
//result: w1 = (30, 30)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, would try this and get back to you

Comment: Operator '-' cannot be applied to Type PointF and Point operands. I tried parsing it but it didn't work as well, the same error

Comment: ```PointF w1 = int.Parse(v1 + (v2 - v1) / 2);``` this is the line of code, I checked on the Microsoft visual studio website and I saw this: The following example creates two PointF objects, then subtracts the second PointF object from the first PointF object and stores the result in a third PointF object.


Copy
PointF point1(40.0f, 10.0f);
PointF point2(-20.0f, -30.0f);

// Point3 now contains the coordinates (60.0f, 40.0f).
PointF point3 = point1 - point2; and PointF::operator-

The PointF::operator- method subtracts the X and Y data members of two PointF objects.

Comment: The addition and subtraction operators on PointF take a SizeF object instead of a PointF object. I've added concrete code in the answer.